# An error occurred while using FindInstance to find a matrix that meets the constraint conditions

Tags: matrix, findinstance

I want to use ***MMA*** to prove an exercise in textbook: `mA` is a n-level square matrix.

Proof: `mA.mA==mA` is true if and only if `MatrixRank[mA]+MatrixRank[IdentityMatrix[n]-mA]==n`.

My code (n=3):

```
Clear["Global`*"];
m0 = ConstantArray[0, {3, 3}];
mA = Array[a, {3, 3}];
miA = IdentityMatrix[3] - mA;
mA2 = mA . mA;

listmA = Flatten[mA];
rankmA = MatrixRank[mA];
rankmiA = MatrixRank[miA];

listmAmBOK1 = 
 FindInstance[(MatrixRank[mA] + MatrixRank[miA] > 3) && (mA == 
     mA . mA), listmA, Reals]
```

> {{a[1, 1] -> 0, a[1, 2] -> 0, a[1, 3] -> 0, a[2, 1] -> 0,
> a[2, 2] -> 0, a[2, 3] -> 0, a[3, 1] -> 0, a[3, 2] -> 0,
> a[3, 3] -> 0}}

```
listmAmBOK2 = 
 FindInstance[(MatrixRank[mA] + MatrixRank[miA] == 3) && (mA == 
     mA . mA), listmA, Reals]
```

> {}

```
listmAmBOK3 = 
 FindInstance[(MatrixRank[mA] + MatrixRank[miA] < 3) && (mA == 
     mA . mA), listmA, Reals]
```

> {}

The results of `listmAmBOK1` and `listmAmBOK2` are obviously wrong.

Because,

```
mAOK1 = mA /. listmAmBOK1[[1]]
```

> {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}

```
miAOK1 = miA /. listmAmBOK1[[1]]
```

> {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}

```
MatrixRank[mAOK1]
```

> 0

```
MatrixRank[miAOK1]
```

> 3

```
MatrixRank[mAOK1] + MatrixRank[miAOK1]
```

> 3

**Can anyone tell me why? How do I modify my code?** Thank you.

Comment: Both `MatrixRank[mA]` and `MatrixRank[miA]` immediately evaluate to `3`, therefore `MatrixRank[mA] + MatrixRank[miA] > 3` evaluates to `True`, and `MatrixRank[mA] + MatrixRank[miA] == 3` evaluates to `False`, even before `FindInstance` starts to do its thing. This is how `MatrixRank` works for symbolic matrices, as explained in the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MatrixRank.html). This explains the results that you get from `FindInstance`.

Comment: @user293787 You are right. Thank you! But I haven't solved the problem of how to modify the code.